# Make WCF Data Services DataServiceContext save only actual changes

Tags: wcf-data-services, silverlight-5.0

I am binding a DataServiceCollection to Silverlight controls using PagedCollectionView. It seems that a record is marked as edited if the User simply sets the focus in and out of certain controls like DatePicker. How can this behavior be intercepted/overridden so only actual changes are sent back to the server for saving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in the Reference.cs file thats autogenerated when you add the Service Reference.
Look at any of the setters and you'll see that the value is pushed straight in without a check like

```
set 
{
  if (this._field == value) return;
  //raise the changing events - not shown
  this._field = value;
  //raise the changed events - not shown
}
```

I wish they'd change it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to say that the whole object is sent for updates instead of only certain properties that have been changed? If yes, you can take a look at this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/12/11/customizing-serialization-of-entities-in-the-ado-net-data-services-client-library.aspx.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: No that is not what I meant. The binding mechanism of DataServiceCollection with Silverlight controls seems to not check if a property value has actually changed before it sends data back to the server, e.g., if there is a FirstInitial field with value 'H', and i delete and retype 'H', the entity is marked as changed and sent to server when save is executed on the DataServiceContext. But that is a great link though, i dont have enough reps to vote u up :)